Is there a way to hide a part of a URL from the address bar while keeping it in $_GET?
I have a website, say, https://example.com, that runs on LAMP stack (Apache2 rewrite_mod activated) and that I would like to make multilingual.
I don’t want my URLs to contain the language/locale, though — I want to only keep them in the $_GET array. So, when clicking a link with the address https://example.com/dev/en, I want to see https://example.com/dev/ in the address bar and [lang] => en in the $_GET array.
Is there a way to do this (with Apache RewriteRules or whatever)?
Here’s how far I’ve got:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dev/(\w+)$ dev?lang=$1

This does rewrite the /en but keeps the parameter in the address bar which I don’t want.

Looks like you don't understand what $_GET is. That array contains parameters from URL so what's not present in URL won't be in $_GET variable. If you want to store selected language without having it in URL you can use cookies or session instead.

FYI: If you want search engines to be able to properly index your different language contents, then you rather do want the language in the URL. Cookies don't help much in that scenario.

The $_GET superglobal is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters (aka. query string). That means it can only contain the contents of the URL parameters. If you'd like to transmit data over a HTTP request without URL parameters, you might consider using the POST method.
The $_POST superglobal can access form data passed with the request, and that can be easy to encode. However, if your example of providing the right language/locale is the goal, this answer implemented a front end form with language selection and a back end script to set the cookie. Since it's a form, it uses POST and the $_POST superglobal for the request.
